# Server Leaks Internal IP Address through content-location on port 443

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssl, iis-6, http-headers

I have 2 servers doing this that use https. I was getting this on both port 80 and 443 but I followed the instructions on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834141/ and resolved the issue with 80.

I am trying to figure out how to repair this on port 443 which I'm confused by since I thought the fix was per site not per port.

This is IIS6 on server 2003

The way I checked this was to telnet to my server then do GET / HTTP/1.0 command. I can't do this through telnet, however, with SSL as far as I know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. When you go do a get / on HTTPS it actually forwards to a different site. I simply applied the fix as described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834141/ to the site it forwarded to which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to check other sites. The Default site was directing to a different site then the https site. This is where the problem lied and I was able to fix it there.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [OpenSSL](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cs-www) to test 443 as you would with telnet on 80.

Comment: I already know the problem exists and I was aware of OpenSSL, but I don't have a linux box ATM nor do I have a compiler handy. I was more wondering if there is a way to specify which port the header name can be changed on.

Comment: There's a Windows binary available. http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html  Sorry, my answer should have been a comment as it only answers a side question.